# Select from a table top 1 row per column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project table and each project can have one or more workflows. Each workflow is composed of one or more steps. Please see the tables defined with data below: (@project, @workflow, @step, @workflowSteps).

Per data shown below we have 2 projects: p1 and p2. 
@ProjectWorkflow table links the project and the workflows. p1 has 2 workflows assigned and p2 has only one workflow assigned.

Workflow 1 has the following steps: start, design approve, finish
Workflow 2 has: start, design, implement, test, finish.

As the project progresses from one step to the next we insert a record into the @ProjectWorkflowSteps table.
The comments in the table definition below describe the steps each project has made.

One more condition needs to be considered. The workflow can be changed. So a project can be assigned workflow 2. It can progress a few steps in that workflow and half way the user can change the workflow to lets say workflow 1. Please see the comments for @ProjectWorkflowSteps below.

Now I want to query the list of all projects (one row per project) with projectID as the first column and the list of steps separated by a comma for the second column, but I only want the last step of each workflow. So basically the query would return the projects and the current step each project is on. For projects with more than workflow (p1) it would return the current step for each of the workflow as shown below:

```
1    approve, implement
2    start
```

Bonus help would be to return the following result:

```
1    approve: 3/4, implement 3/5
2    start: 1/4
```

Basically for each workflow list the current step, the completed steps so far / total number of steps in the workflow.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Thank you at Gyromite for your answer. I am using it here to clarify the question.

```
DECLARE @project TABLE (projectID INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @project
VALUES
(1, 'p1'),
(2, 'p2');


DECLARE @Step TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @Step
VALUES
(1, 'start'),
(2, 'finish'),
(3, 'test'),
(4, 'implement'),
(5, 'approve'),
(6, 'design');
DECLARE @Workflow TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @Workflow
VALUES
(1, 'workflow1'),
(2, 'worfklow2');

DECLARE @WorkflowSteps TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, workflowID INT, stepID     INT);
INSERT @WorkflowSteps
VALUES
(1, 1, 1), --workflow1 steps: start, design approve, finish
(2, 1, 6),
(3, 1, 5),
(4, 1, 2),

(5, 2, 1),  --Workflow2: start, design, implement, test, finish
(6, 2, 6),
(7, 2, 4),
(8, 2, 3),
(9, 2, 2);


DECLARE @projectWorkflow TABLE (projectworkflowID INT PRIMARY KEY, projectID INT, workflowID INT);
INSERT @projectWorkflow
VALUES
(1, 1, 1), --proejct 1 has two workflows
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 2);  --project 2 has only one workflow


DECLARE @ProjectWorkflowSteps TABLE (PWSID INT PRIMARY KEY, projectworkflowID INT, projectID INT, workflowID INT, stepID INT);
INSERT @ProjectWorkflowSteps (PWSID, projectWorkflowID, projectID, workflowID, stepID)
VALUES
(1, 1,1,1,1),  --project 1 has 2 workflows assigned to it
(2, 1,1,1,6),  --on workflow 1 it progressed thru 2 steps 
(3, 1,1,1,5),  --and is currently on the third step: approve step (ID=5)

(4, 2,1,2,1),  --project 1 -> second workflow, also progressed 2 steps
(5, 2,1,2,2),  --and is currently on third stepID = 4: 'implement'
(6, 2,1,2,4),  --


(7, 3,2,2,1), --project 2 was assigned workflowID 2 for the first two steps. 
(8, 3,2,2,2), -- then it was changed to workflowID = 1
(9, 3,2,1,1); -- PWID is still 3 here, but workflowID is changed from 2 -> 1
```

EDIT 2:
The following query gives me what I want, but I am wondering if it can be performed in a more efficient manner.

```
    SELECT p.projectID,
Stuff ((SELECT ',  ' + s.name 
           FROM   (SELECT * 
                   FROM   @projectWorkflow) pw 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                                   FROM   (SELECT projectworkflowID, 
                                  pwsID, 
                                  stepID, 
                       Row_number() OVER(partition BY ProjectworkflowID 
                                      ORDER BY pwsid DESC) rn 
                                           FROM   @ProjectWorkflowSteps 
                                           WHERE  projectID = p.projectID) 
                                          ppp 
                                   WHERE  rn = 1) pws 
                               ON pw.projectworkflowID = pws.projectworkflowid 
                  INNER JOIN @step s 
                          ON s.ID = pws.stepID
           FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [Steps]
FROM   @project p 
GROUP  BY p.projectID
```

Comment: I tried several things.. I ran into issues where I cannot do an order by on a temp table.. and another one I tried to join but couldn't access the column in another temp table.

Comment: It would be nice to have the options that you have tried with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this can help you get the results you want.

```
DECLARE @ProjectStatus TABLE (PWID INT, projectID INT, workflowID INT, stepID INT);
INSERT @ProjectStatus (PWID, projectID, workflowID, stepID)
    VALUES
    (1,1,1,1),
    (1,1,1,2),
    (1,1,1,3),
    (2,1,2,1),
    (2,1,2,2),
    (2,1,2,4),
    (3,2,2,1),
    (3,2,2,2),
    (3,2,1,1);
DECLARE @Step TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @Step
    VALUES
    (1, 'start'),
    (2, 'design'),
    (3, 'approve'),
    (4, 'implement');
SELECT PS1.projectID
    ,stuff( -- using Stuff to remove the leading comma in the concatenated string.
        (   SELECT ', ' + St.name
            FROM
            (   SELECT PS2.projectID, PS2.workflowID, MAX(PS2.stepID) AS stepID
                FROM @ProjectStatus AS PS2
                GROUP BY PS2.projectID, PS2.workflowID
            ) AS PSWorkflowStep
            INNER JOIN @Step AS St ON St.ID = PSWorkflowStep.stepID
            WHERE PSWorkflowStep.projectID = PS1.projectID
            ORDER BY PSWorkflowStep.workflowID
            for xml path('') -- For XML PATH is the method I'm using for concatenating multiple rows into one.
            -- This next line translates the XML back to text (to avoid issues with special characters @,&,<,>) but it is expensive in CPU.  You may remove it if you don't need it.
            , root('XMLVal'), type).value('/XMLVal[1]','varchar(max)'
        )
    , 1, 2, '') AS workflowSteps
FROM @ProjectStatus AS PS1
GROUP BY PS1.projectID
ORDER BY PS1.projectID
```

The results returned are these:

```
projectID   workflowSteps
1   approve, implement
2   start, design
```

There are a few parts in the description that I don't understand, so I made a couple of assumptions.  It looks like maybe there is an error in your first sample table, where step ID of 1 is commented as both "start" and "design", so I'm assuming that step ID 1 should be "start".  Also, I don't see the relevance of the paragraph where you talk about "The workflow can be changed," so I left that out of my example.  Finally, regarding your bonus help result, I don't see from your model how to tell which is the current step for a given workflow, so I didn't attempt that part.

In the future, if you could please include the T-SQL script to re-create your example (tables and data), that would make it much easier for someone to help write a query for you.

Comment: Good effort on a question that's a bit vague. I especially appreciate that you understand that `STUFF()` is separate from the XML functionality, some people conflate the two, which is a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Thank you. However, there are a few issues with the query and some of it has to do with the part that you omitted. I am editing the question to make it more clear. Thanks